# The system cannot find the file specified (django)

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

Hi I'm creating pdf file but I face an error **[WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified** but I don't know where is the error

```
if os.path.exists(pdf_file_output):
    with open(pdf_file_output, 'rb') as fh:
        response = HttpResponse(fh.read(), content_type="application/pdf")
        response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=' + os.path.basename(pdf_file_output)
        return response
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code is unable to locate the file specified (probably in Windows). There are few reasons:

Wrong file path: Check if that `pdf_file_output` file path is correct and the file is exist in that location.

Permission problem: Make sure that the current user has permissions to access the file.

Typo in the filename: Check if that there are no typos in the file name and the file name is the same as you're trying to access.

Alternative script that helps you to debug your code:

```
import os

pdf_file_output = ...

if os.path.exists(pdf_file_output):
    with open(pdf_file_output, 'rb') as fh:
        response = HttpResponse(fh.read(), content_type="application/pdf")
        response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=' + 
os.path.basename(pdf_file_output)
            return response
else:
    print(f"The file '{pdf_file_output}' doesn't exist.")
```